# Adobe CQ - Redirecting to external URL

Tags: java, adobe, aem

I want to redirect to some external URL based on some logic. But the dispatcher cache starts looking for the relative path and then redirects the URL to the internal domain.

For eg. my application URL is http://example.com/content/us/homepage.html

based on some logic, I want the user to redirect to some external URL for eg

http://example222.com/content/us/en/markets.html

Dispatcher tries to search /content/us/en/markets.html in the cache and when this is not found, redirects to the URL http://example.com/content/us/en/markets.html

Is there any configuration that we need to add to support the redirection to the external URLs.

The code logic to redirect to external url is

```
 slingResponse.setStatus(301);
 slingResponse.setHeader("Location", redirectPageURL);
 slingResponse.setHeader("Connection", "close");
```

Comment: Could you paste an excerpt of the redirecting code?

Comment: code snippet to redirect has been added.

Comment: What is the value of `redirectPageURL`, is it relative URL?